# Missing SERVICE PLAN information while creating Cloud Foundry Service in IBM cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to create a cloud service for mysql in Ibm Cloud via Cloud Foundry.
From terminal after logging into IBM cloud via cf login , i am trying to create a db service using the following command

```
$ cf create-service mysql free first-push-db
```

However i get the error message

```
The plan 'Free' could not be found for service offering 'mysql'.
```

The documentation is not conclusive on the cloud foundry website and mentions that the plan 'varies'
https://tutorials.cloudfoundry.org/trycf/docs/provisioning/

How does one get to know what are the 'plans' available for the Pay-As-You-Go account on Ibm Cloud ?

Answer (score 1):

You might already have seen that [Cloud Foundry on IBM Cloud is deprecated](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-getting-started) and new projects should not be started.

The way you use the CF CLI to create services works in IBM Cloud, but it is not the recommended way. Because of the deprecation it is probably not worth getting into details, but

- use the IBM Cloud CLI with the CF plugin to manage your apps and services
- provision services with the `ibmcloud resource` commands, then create an alias for Cloud Foundry
- check for plans and pricing with the `ibmcloud catalog` command (or in the browser UI)